# javascript escape backslash but not a backslash quote (escaped quote)

Tags: javascript, replace

I have some array data embedded in a html data attribute. Any quotes are being escaped ( \" ) already.

```
["A\A/A\"INC",3]
```

In my javascript I have a function to escape backslashes

```
if(typeof dataarray === "string") {
  dataarray = dataarray.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
}
```

but then it breaks because I am escaping the escaped quote backslash

```
["A\\A/A\\"INC",3]
```

Is there a better way to replace backslashes while leaving \" intact?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead expression to ensure the next character is not a quote:

```
dataarray.replace(/\\(?!")/g,"\\\\");
```

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> #### `x(?!y)`
>
> Matches `x` only if `x` is not followed by `y`. For example, `/\d+(?!\.)/` matches a number only if it is not followed by a decimal point.
>
> `/\d+(?!\.)/.exec("3.141")` matches 141 but not 3.141.